# how to create multidimensional array / object in jquery and pass via AJAX post

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, object, multidimensional-array

I am creating an order form that has a table of order items users can purchase. The inputs are using data attributes to store the items name and price per piece like so:

```
<input type="text" class="input-small quantity-input" data-pid="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>" data-min="<?php echo $p['min_qty']; ?>" data-max="<?php echo $p['max_qty']; ?>" data-price="<?php echo $p['price']; ?>" data-name="<?php echo $p['product_name']; ?>" placeholder="quantity...">
```

I have everything figured out except for how to iterate over each quantity-input item and add it to a multidimensional array that I can send via an AJAX Post. I currently have the following code, but when I do a print_r on the $_POST value it says: Disallowed Key Characters: Fresh Tilapia Filets

```
    $("#ccform").validate({
  rules: {
    firstName: { required: true },
    lastName: { required: true },
    email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
    },
    cardNumber: { required: true },
    expMonth: { required: true },
    expYear: { required: true },
    cvv: { required: true },
    address: { required: true },
    city: { required: true },
    state: { required: true },
    zipcode: { required: true },
    phone: { required: true },
  },
  submitHandler: function() {
      var siteUrl = $('#siteUrl').val();
      var orderItems = [];
        $('.quantity-input').each(function(){
            var orderItem = $(this).attr('data-name');
            var priceEach = $(this).attr('data-price');
            var qty = $(this).val();
            if(qty != '') {
                obj = {};
                obj[orderItem] = orderItem;
                obj[priceEach] = priceEach;
                obj[qty] = qty;
                orderItems.push(obj);
            }
        });

        var pickupLocation = $('input[name="pickup"]:checked').val();
        var pickupPrice = $('#hidePickupPrice').val();
        var subtotal = $('#hideSubtotal').val();
        var tax = $('#hideTax').val();
        var total = $('#hideTotal').val();

        var firstName = $('#firstName').val();
        var lastName = $('#lastName').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var cardNumber = $('#cardNumber').val();
        var expMonth = $('#expMonth').val();
        var expYear = $('#expYear').val();
        var cvv = $('#cvv').val();
        var address = $('#address').val();
        var address2 = $('#address2').val();
        var city = $('#city').val();
        var state = $('#state').val();
        var zipcode = $('#zipcode').val();
        var phone = $('#phone').val();

        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: siteUrl + "frontend/pay",
             data: ({ 'orderItems': orderItems, 'pickupLocation': pickupLocation, 'pickupPrice': pickupPrice, 'subtotal': subtotal, 'tax': tax, 'total': total, 'firstName': firstName, 'lastName': lastName, 'email': email, 'cardNumber': cardNumber, 'expMonth': expMonth, 'expYear': expYear, 'cvv': cvv, 'address': address, 'address2': address2, 'city': city, 'state': state, 'zipcode': zipcode, 'phone': phone}),
             success: function(data) {
                 alert('done!');
             }
        });
    },
});
```

I don't usually get into Jquery this much, so it may just be a noob problem with the formatting of the jquery object. Also, I'm using Codeigniter for the PHP framework. [You can see the live version here](http://422clients.com/f2f/app)

To clarify, this is the area of the code I need help with. It is not creating a multi dimensional object / array:

```
var orderItems = [];
        $('.quantity-input').each(function(){
            var orderItem = $(this).attr('data-name');
            var priceEach = $(this).attr('data-price');
            var qty = $(this).val();
            if(qty != '') {
                obj = {};
                obj[orderItem] = orderItem;
                obj[priceEach] = priceEach;
                obj[qty] = qty;
                orderItems.push(obj);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you know about http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/?

Comment: Yes I could easily serialize the bottom credit card form. I'm not asking about that. I'm asking how I can create the jquery equivalent of a multidimensional array by using the .each function on the quantity-inputs since those inputs use data elements to specify what items are being ordered.

Comment: All javascript arrays are uni-dimensional. However, they can be nested, one inside another.

Comment: Maybe this/JSON could help: http://iviewsource.com/codingtutorials/getting-started-with-javascript-object-notation-json-for-absolute-beginners/? Off topic, but, i hope that your client will not collect credit card data from customers?

Comment: no this is a setup to use Authorize.net CIM. Its PCI compliant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to quote your keys:

```
obj['orderItem'] = orderItem;
obj['priceEach'] = priceEach;
obj['qty'] = qty;
```

Or use dot notation:

```
obj.orderItem = orderItem;
obj.priceEach = priceEach;
obj.qty = qty;
```

Without the quotes/dot notation its like saying:

```
obj['Fresh Tilapia Filets'] = 'Fresh Tilapia Filets';
obj['$2.99'] = '$2.99';
obj[10] = 10;
```

Because its evaluating the variables with the same name.

Comment: worked perfectly, I figured it would be something easy. Not used to working with Jquery like that. lol. Thanks for the help.