# jQuery / AJAX multidimensional Array

Tags: arrays, jquery

I am trying to parse some XML stored online and then save each parent node and its children through PHP.

As a test I have created a bit of basic XML as the online one is very very long.
I have a bit of XML which I am trying to achieve the basics with.

```
<result>
    <name>Person1</name>
    <date>2002-05-16</date>        
</result>
<result>
    <name>Person2</name>
    <date>2012-11-06</date>
</result>
```

I want to display each result separately in the following html:

```
<body>
    <p>XML Split</p>
    <div id="contents"></div>
        <div id="scroll"><input type="button" id="next" Value=" next in array "/>
        <input type="button" id="previous" Value=" previous in array "/></div>
        <div id="save"><input type="button" id="one" Value=" Save xml "/>
        <input type="button" id="all" Value=" Save all xml "/></div>
    <p>XML Split ended</p>
</body>
```

To do this I am using the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "sampleContent.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: ({'name': name, 'date': date}),
    success: function(xml) {
        parseXml(xml);
        append();
    }
});
});

var tmpName;
var tmpDate;
var results = [];

function parseXml(xml) {

$(xml).find('result').each(function() {

    tmpName = $(this).find('name').text();
    tmpDate = $(this).find('date').text();
    output = $(this).val();
    if (output != ''){
        obj = {};
        obj.name = name;
        obj.date = date;
        obj.output = output;
        results.push(obj);
    }
});
}

function append() {

$(results).each(function() {

    $('#contents').append('<div id="record"><div class="name">' +
            tmpName + '</div><div class="date">' +
            tmpDate + '</div></div>');
});
}
```

I am struggling to get the XML data to display when I try and create an Array. I will also need to ammend some of the variable that are used in the array such as the date from year- month-day -> day-month-year.

I am unsure how or why this is going wrong so would appreciate any suggestions about creating the Array needed. I have been trying to use [how to create multidimensional array / object in jquery and pass via AJAX post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003748/how-to-create-multidimensional-array-object-in-jquery-and-pass-via-ajax-post?rq=1) as an example but am still going wrong.

Any and all suggestions welcome.

Thanks

Dan

Comment: In your `append()` function, use the values from your array instead of using `tmpName` and `tmpDate`

Answer (score 0):

In your `append()` function, use the values from your array instead of using `tmpName` and `tmpDate`

```
$(results).each(function(i) {
    $('#contents').append('<div id="record"><div class="name">' +
            results[i].name + '</div><div class="date">' +
            results[i].date + '</div></div>');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, i have amended as your suggestion shows but am still not getting any output.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things

1. It seems like `result` is at root level, `find()` only finds
   descendants
2. The global variables will change in the loop, and equal
   the last value after the loop
3. `if (output != ''){...` will never be true, as the `result` elements have no value

-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "sampleContent.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: {
            name : name,
            date : date
        }
    }).done(function(xml) {
        $('<div />').append(xml).find('result').each(function () {
            var record = $('<div />', {
                    id : 'record'
                }),
                name   = $('<div />', {
                    'class' : 'name',
                    html    : $(this).find('name').text()
                }),
                date   = $('<div />', {
                    'class' : 'date',
                    html    : $(this).find('date').text()
                });

            $('#contents').append( record.append(name, date) );
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, maybe a little more confused now though, should this be a complete re-write of what i have done? I have tried copying it all across, and have tried replacing my functions for parseXml() and append() with a new function for .done. Am still not getting any output. As for 'if (output != ''){... will never be true, as the result elements have no value', am i wrong in trying to .push the name and date objects into the array for results? Therefore creating an obj array called results?

Comment: @PartTimeNinja - `val()` gets value, as in `<input value="something" />`, and `<result>` has no value, so `val()` will always return an empty string. You're not wrong in creating an array, but you're iterating to create an array, then you're iterating to use the array, when you can just use the values right away, the array is not really needed. You've set the dataType to `xml`, so you don't need `$.parseXML`, jQuery does that for you, and `done` is the same as `success` really, so this should hopefully replace the code you have. Try console logging `xml` at the first line inside `done` ?